# bluestore_mic_alloc_size not getting picked up by ceph daemons

Tags: filesystems, ceph, cephfs, rook-storage, kubernetes-rook

I am applying this bluestore_min_alloc_size to 4096, no matter how I apply the setting, it not getting picked up by daemons, I have tried to restart all daemons pod also after applying the setting but no effect.

```
[root@rook-ceph-tools-55c94c6786-x88d2 /]# ceph config get osd bluestore_min_alloc_size
4096
[root@rook-ceph-tools-55c94c6786-x88d2 /]# ceph config get osd.0 bluestore_min_alloc_size
4096
[root@rook-ceph-tools-55c94c6786-x88d2 /]# ceph config get osd.0 bluestore_min_alloc_size_hdd
4096
[root@rook-ceph-tools-55c94c6786-x88d2 /]# ceph config get osd.0 bluestore_min_alloc_size_ssd
4096
[root@rook-ceph-tools-55c94c6786-x88d2 /]# ceph config dump
WHO               MASK  LEVEL     OPTION                                 VALUE   RO
global                  basic     log_to_file                            false
global                  advanced  mon_allow_pool_delete                  true
global                  advanced  mon_cluster_log_file
global                  advanced  mon_pg_warn_min_per_osd                0
global                  advanced  osd_pool_default_pg_autoscale_mode     on
global                  advanced  osd_scrub_auto_repair                  true
global                  advanced  rbd_default_features                   3
  mon                   advanced  auth_allow_insecure_global_id_reclaim  false
  mgr                   advanced  mgr/balancer/active                    true
  mgr                   advanced  mgr/balancer/mode                      upmap
    mgr.a               advanced  mgr/dashboard/server_port              8443    *
    mgr.a               advanced  mgr/dashboard/ssl                      true    *
    mgr.a               advanced  mgr/dashboard/ssl_server_port          8443    *
  osd                   advanced  bluestore_min_alloc_size               4096    *
    osd.0               advanced  bluestore_min_alloc_size_hdd           4096    *
    osd.0               advanced  bluestore_min_alloc_size_ssd           4096    *
    mds.iondfs-a        basic     mds_join_fs                            iondfs
    mds.iondfs-b        basic     mds_join_fs                            iondfs
```

**ceph df**

```
[root@rook-ceph-tools-55c94c6786-x88d2 /]# ceph df
--- RAW STORAGE ---
CLASS  SIZE    AVAIL   USED     RAW USED  %RAW USED
hdd    43 GiB  39 GiB  4.0 GiB   5.0 GiB      11.45
TOTAL  43 GiB  39 GiB  4.0 GiB   5.0 GiB      11.45

--- POOLS ---
POOL                   ID  PGS  STORED   OBJECTS  USED     %USED  MAX AVAIL
device_health_metrics   1    1      0 B        0      0 B      0     12 GiB
iondfs-metadata         2   32  240 MiB      128  241 MiB   0.64     36 GiB
iondfs-data0            3   32  209 MiB   60.80k  3.8 GiB   9.41     36 GiB
```

**you can see stored size of 60.80k objects is 209MB but used is 3.8Gb that is 64x60.8x1000 kb = 3.8912 Gb
That showing that still 64k block size is being used instead of 4kb**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch is option **blustore_min_alloc_size** cant be set aftet osd is created, you need to create config before creating the cluster.

kubectl create namespace rook-ceph

save below as `ceph-conf.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: rook-config-override
  namespace: rook-ceph
data:
  config: |
    [osd]
    bluestore_min_alloc_size = 4096
    bluestore_min_alloc_size_hdd = 4096
    bluestore_min_alloc_size_ssd = 4096
```

kubectl apply -f ceph-conf.yaml

Now create the ceph cluster